# Ввод ФИО в один TextBox, маска

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли реализовать, и если да, то как, такую затею. TextBox, в нём маска на ввод трёх слов - ФИО. Пробовал такую маску: "L L L", она конечно не сработала, т.к. даёт ввести по одному символу между пробелами, а нужно неограниченное количество символов. Регулярки использовать здесь не хочу, нужно именно чтобы в текстбоксе были символы нижнего подчёркивания, указывающие место для ввода

Comment: TextBox есть в WPF и WinForms, укажите нужный тэг.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью маски это не решить. Вам нужно валидировать ввод постфактум. Варианта два:

1. Валидация символов на этапе ввода. Простой вариант -- реагировать на нажатие клавиши, [продвинутый вариант](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/2608/c-validating-textbox-control) -- валидировать полноценно (WinForms). Аналогичное решение можно соорудить и для WPF.
2. Валидация введенного текста целиком при помощи регулярных выражений.

Если вы хотите проверять русские ФИО, то помните, что кроме букв в них *как минимум* могут содержаться еще и дефисы. Если хотите проверять также и иностранные имена, написанные кириллицей, то все становится еще сложнее: тут вам и цифры, и апострофы, и запятые, и точки, и черт знает что еще. А если иностранные имена еще и в оригинале, то вообще все плохо :).

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ) Буду юзать регулярки тогда

Comment: @Antykus не за что! Можете отметить его как верный (галка левее ответа).